# how to integrate $\log{_x}{(a)}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus

can you write me how is the $\log{_x}{(a)}$ function called and what is the intuition behind it? I want to calculate $\int{\log{_x}{(a)}\,dx}$.

Comment: $log{_x}{(a)}dx=\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}$, where $\ln a$ is a constant.

Comment: @Vega ok, but how integrate $\frac{1}{\ln{x}}dx$?

Comment: It is a special integral. Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: @test : $$\int log_x(a)dx=\ln(a)*\text{li}(x)+\text{constant}$$ li$(x)$ is a standard special function. Are you familiar with the use of special functions? If not : A paper for general public, pp.18-36 https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales .

Comment: @JJacquelin thank you